# Prove that $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} x^2, &x \le 1 \\ 3 - 2x, &x > 1 \end{array} \right.\;$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that

$$
f(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
x^2, &x \le 1 \\ 
3 - 2x, &x > 1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and that Range $f = \mathbb{R}$

What I have so far is..   
Given $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(p)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - p| < \delta$
 
Consider $p > 0$ then we have

for $x \le 1$
$$|f(x) - f(p)| = |x^2 - p^2| = |x - p||x + p|$$
Choose $\delta = p$ so $|x - p| < p$ then we get $-p < x - p < p\;\;$ to $\;\;p < x + p < 3p$

Then since $x + p < 3p $ we have $$|x - p||x + p| = 3p|x - p|$$
Let $\delta = min\{p, \frac{\delta}{3p}\}$
$$3p|x - p| < 3p\delta < \frac{3p\epsilon}{3p} = \epsilon$$
Then I do the same $x > 1$, then again for both $p = 0$ and $p < 0$?

Comment: Any polynomial is continuous. I think you should check the continuity only at 1.

Comment: Oh wait, I should be checking it for $p \le 1$ and $p > 1$... I think

Comment: Whenever $p\neq 1$, $f(x)$ is continuous at $p$. I think you should only check when $p=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \ne 1$ you have an elementary function, that is known as continous.

So you have to check only when $x = 1$:

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = 1^2 = 1 = \lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x) = 3 - 2 = 1 = f(1) = 1.$$

You've shown that $\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x) = f(1)$ which is the define of *pointwise continous.*

Proven.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the following way also .

For a function to be continuous at a point the left-hand side limit , right-hand side limit and the value of the function at that point should all be same .

Therefore we can see

$$\lim_{x\to1^-}x^2 = 1$$

at $1$ , $$f(1)=1^2 = 1$$

and $$\lim_{x\to1^+}3-2x = 1$$

Hence the function is continuous at $x=1$ . At all the other places it is continuous